# The 'gnome-session' command is not working, but when i put --debug, I found out

Tags: 20.04, gnome

When I type `gnome-session` in my WSL terminal, I had to wait a few seconds and then I come back to the prompt. but when I used `--debug` in `gnome-session`, I found out what happened.
Here Is the text I got from the terminal:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/19MPIC-wOxz1EvIChBBTtHgxqn2c6Rwi5/view?usp=sharing

I can't fix this myself. I was Using for my GUI setup.

Comment: I used a link because i need to save space in the body because the text from the terminal was so long that i had to put a link to my google drive.